# C++ Vigenere Cipher

Tags: c++, string, vigenere

I wrote this code for Vigenere Cipher in C++ (Assuming the plaintext and the key is in lowercase).

```
void encrypt(string& plaintext , string key){
int j = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++){

     //cout<<"value of key["<<j<<"] = "<<int(key[j])<<endl;

     plaintext[i] -= 97;
     key[j] -= 97;

     plaintext[i] = ((plaintext[i] + key[j])%26)+97;

     j = (j+1)%key.length();
  }
}
```

The problem is that when 'j' gets reset to 0 , key[j] turns out to be NULL(0).
For eg. If I assume the **plaintext to be 'human'** and **key to be 'abcd'** the first 4 characters of the plaintext are encrypted correctly but for the last character the key[j] value is turning out to be 0 or Null instead of going back to 'a'.

I am not sure why this is happening. I guess string class handles Null values implicitly so that makes it even more confusing to me.

Comment: Check what `key.length()`. For the "abcd" key it should obviously be 4, but based on your description it must be 5. Whatever code set the value of `key`, it did that incorrectly, and that's where the bug is, not here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried printing it and it shows 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
key[j] -= 97;
```

On the first pass through the key, this chunk of code will scribble all over it.

If `key` was "abcd", on second pass it will now be 0.

Do not modify `key` in your function. Since that parameter should not be changed, it should be declared as `const std::string key`, or, better yet, `const std::string &key`. If it was done that way, the compiler would've caught this bug for you.